# Using a function on a list of .tif files to sort by size (based on pixels)

Tags: r, function, lapply

As the question states, I am trying to sort 1000s of tif files based on pixel height and width (for ecological purposes for anyone interested!)

I have written a function that, using the `magick` package that creates a simple image size, achieved by `imageinfo$width*imageinfo$height`, see more below. This is compared to a threshold that decides if its big or small. The function is working correctly but I am struggling to run `lapply` on the list, it gives an error message with the `image_read` function from `magick`.

```
threshold <- 90000
dirsmallimages <- "C:/Users/James PC/Desktop/smallimages"
dirbigimages<- "C:/Users/James PC/Desktop/bigimages"

imagelist <- as.list(list.files(
  path = "C:/Users/James PC/Desktop",
  full.names = TRUE,
  recursive = FALSE,
  pattern = ".tif"
))

bigsmallsorter <- function(singleimage){
  imagepreview <- image_read(singleimage)
  imagepreview
  imageinfo <- image_info(imagepreview)
  imagesize <- as.numeric(imageinfo$width*imageinfo$height)

  if(imagesize > threshold){
    file.copy(from = singleimage, to = dirbigimages, overwrite = TRUE)
  } else {
    file.copy(from = singleimage, to = dirsmallimages, overwrite = TRUE)
  }
}

lapply(imagelist, FUN = bigsmallsorter(singleimage = imagelist)) # this is kaput
```

Error:

```
 Error in image_read(singleimage) : 
  path must be URL, filename or raw vector
```

I currently am just trying to get this working on a list with one big `[[1]]` and one small `[[2]]`:

```
> imagelist
[[1]]
[1] "C:/Users/James PC/Desktop/Pia1.2017-10-03.1726+N00007823_hc.tif"
[[2]]
[1] "C:/Users/James PC/Desktop/Pia1.2017-10-08.1928+N00691602_hc.tif"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as sorting the images manually is a total pain in the butt!

Many thanks

Comment: Get rid of `as.list` from `list.files()`

Comment: thanks for responding! no joy I am afriad, same error!

Comment: And along with that, `lapply(imagelist, FUN = bigsmallsorter)`

Comment: Oh, as simple as that! Cheers, I also had this in the code 'lapply(imagelist, function(bigsmallsorter))', so close! Answer it if you wish!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two key things:

One, `list.files` already outputs an iterable data structure, so there's no need to wrap it in `as.list()`.

Two, your construction of `lapply` isn't quite right. `lapply` passes the first argument to the second `FUN` argument. By specifying `bigsmallsorter(singleimage = imagelist)`, you're trying to pass your list of files, to your function that takes a single argument, which directly conflicts with how `lapply` works.

Instead, we let `lapply` pass each list item to `bigsmallsorter`, like this:

```
lapply(imagelist, FUN = bigsmallsorter)
```

You can equivalently write:

```
lapply(imagelist, bigsmallsorter)
```

A slightly more verbose way to write this is:

```
lapply(imagelist, FUN = function(x) bigsmallsorter(singleimage = x))
```

Where `x` represents the variable through which `imagelist` is passed, one at a time.

Comment: many thanks!! `does the reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 3661 entries` mean that those 3661 entries have not been processed?

Comment: @Jim no, `getOption("max.print")` just references the maximum number of lines that will be printed to the console, before being truncated.